# How to integrate web sockets with a django wsgi

Tags: django, websocket, wsgi, gevent, gunicorn

We have a significantly complex Django application currently served by
apache/mod_wsgi and deployed on multiple AWS EC2 instances behind a
AWS ELB load balancer. Client applications interact with the server
using AJAX.  They also periodically poll the server to retrieve notifications
and updates to their state. We wish to remove the polling and replace
it with "push", using web sockets.

Because arbitrary instances handle web socket requests from clients
and hold onto those web sockets, and because we wish to push data to
clients who may not be on the same instance that provides the source
data for the push, we need a way to route data to the appropriate
instance and then from that instance to the appropriate client web
socket.

We realize that apache/mod_wsgi do not play well with web sockets and
plan to replace these components with nginx/gunicorn and use the
gevent-websocket worker.  However, if one of several worker processes
receive requests from clients to establish a web socket, and if the
lifetime of worker processes is controlled by the main gunicorn
process, it isn't clear how other worker processes, or in fact
non-gunicorn processes can send data to these web sockets.

A specific case is this one: A user who issues a HTTP request is
directed to one EC2 instance (host) and the desired behavior is that data is
to be sent to another user who has a web socket open in a completely
different instance.  One can easily envision a system where a message
broker (e.g. rabbitmq) running on each instance can be sent a message
containing the data to be sent via web sockets to the client connected
to that instance.  But how can the handler of these messages access
the web socket, which was received in a worker process of gunicorn?
The high-level python web socket objects created gevent-websocket and
made available to a worker cannot be pickled (they are instance
methods with no support for pickling), so they cannot easily be shared
by a worker process to some long-running, external process.

In fact, the root of this question comes down to how can web sockets
which are initiated by HTTP requests from clients and handled by WSGI
handlers in servers such as gunicorn be accessed by external
processes?  It doesn't seem *right* that gunicorn worker processes,
which are intended to handle HTTP requests would spawn long-running
threads to hang onto web sockets and support handling messages from
other processes to send messages to the web sockets that have been
attached through those worker processes.

Can anyone explain how web sockets and WSGI-based HTTP request
handlers can possibly interplay in the environment I've described?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've made the correct assesment that mod_wsgi + websockets is a nasty combination.

You would find all of your wsgi workers hogged by the web sockets and an attempt to (massively) increase the size of the worker pool would probably choke the server because of the memory usage and context switching.

If you like to stick with the synchronous wsgi worker architecture (as opposed to the reactive approach implemented by gevent, twisted, tornado etc), I would suggest looking into uWSGI as a application server. Recent versions can handle some URLs in the old way (i.e. your existing django views would still work the same as before), and route other urls to a async websocket handler. This might be a relatively smooth migration path for you.

Comment: We have since switched to a model where we use NGINX as our HTTP proxy and have it proxy to either gunicorn (django) or nodejs. The nodejs app handles our web sockets. We may, soon, switch away from gunicorn and try uWSGI, as we believe the performance will be better.  Whether we switch the websockets support back to python/django or not will depend on whether we really think there is much advantage to doing so.  Nodejs seems to be handling these websocket connections fine now.

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't seem right that gunicorn worker processes, which are intended to handle HTTP requests would spawn long-running threads to hang onto web sockets and support handling messages from other processes to send messages to the web sockets that have been attached through those worker processes.

Why not? This is a long-running connection, after all. A long-running thread to take care of such a connection would seem... absolutely natural to me.

Often in these evented situations, writing is handled separately from reading.

A worker that is currently handling a websocket connection would wait for relevant message to come down from a messaging server, and then pass that down the websocket.

You can also use gevent's async-friendly Queues to handle in-code message passing, if you like.

Comment: If, as a result of handling one HTTP request, the server needs to send a push notification down the websocket that another user has connected to another worker process on either the same host or a different host, the sending worker must queue a message (somewhere, but perhaps to a AMQP server that each worker is subscribed to) and the receiving worker (the one who is holding onto the websocket from the target client) would have to read the message from the queue and send it down the web socket.

Does this seem like a reasonable architecture?

Comment: I had not felt comfortable with using the worker processes for "other work" than request/response processing, but you appear to be saying there is no reason why they couldn't.  Right?

Comment: Well a websocket is no longer doing simple request/response handling, is it? It's now a full-blown duplex channel.

You could hand websocket connections off to separate pool of workers, if you liked. 

Yes, what you suggested seems like a normal arch. to me. :)